# How to turn off auto start on-screen-keyboard on Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, 64-bit, on-screen-keyboard

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit in a Laptop HP Elitebook 8460p I really don't like the keyboard so I plugged in an external usb keyboard and it worked fine, but accidentally I kept pressing the keys cause I work with the usb keyboard above the laptop keyboard so I decided to disable the standard laptop keyboard from "device manager", but as a result now everytime I turn on the cpu the on-screen-keyboard is launched, and the standard keyboard is also still automatically enabled.

So I want to know how can I stop launching the on-screen-keyboard each time I start the cpu, cause I tried with msconfig searching process for osk.exe, but can't find it.

I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto `Control Panel - ease of access center - use the computer without a mouse or keyboard` and uncheck the `use on-screen keyboard` box

Comment: Yes, that switched off the Keyboard. Sadly the task bar icon is still there which seems to be quite a buggy.