# How to turn Windows' "touch mode" off?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, touchpad

After installing a touch pad driver on my laptop, it seems somehow my Windows turn on some kind of "touch mode". There's a touch keyboard icon on the task bar, I tried to turn it off but it keeps coming back when the system restarts. Also, the Adobe Reader opens in "touch mode" and the Microsoft Office programs have touch options on the Quick Access Toolbar.

It seems the programs somehow think I have a touch screen so they behave like they are running on touch devices but I really don't.

I don't want to uninstall the touch pad driver, how can I make the programs behave normally as if they were running on a desktop?

- Laptop: Dell Vostro 2421;
- OS: Windows 8.

After some digging, I found it may be related to two process: SynTPEnh.exe & SynTPHelper.exe. If I stop these two process, it comes back to normal. Is it related to the problem? It there a "nonviolent" way to configure the driver other than just killing the two processes?

Comment: Check [here](http://superuser.com/questions/622910/how-to-turn-off-auto-start-on-screen-keyboard-on-windows-7-64-bit) might be related, but it's for Win 7

Comment: It's not only about the touch screen, it's a system thing. And the option "use on-screen keyboard" has always been unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

One simply way would be to simply disable the device or uninstall the driver for the device.

Otherwise the following might help

- Press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
- Type "services," and press Enter
- Scroll down to "Touch screen keyboard and handwriting panel"
- You can either right click and "Stop" or you can double-click and
  change it from "Automatic" startup to "Manual."

This will of course, disable both the touch keyboard and handwriting service, so you'll lose handwriting recognition.

[Source](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToDisableTheOnScreenTouchKeyboardInWindows8.aspx)

Comment: It doesn't work, it just disabled the touch screen keyboard, but the icon stays. Just when click the icon nothing happens. Also, it doesn't affect Adobe Reader.